# Scheme - run two procedures from arguments sequentially?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to create a function that takes two functions as arguments and executes both of them.

I tried using `cond`, but it only executes `action1`.

```
(define seq-action
  (lambda (action1 action2)
    (cond
     ((procedure? action1) (action1))
     ((procedure? action2) (action2)))))
```

I feel like it shouldn't be too hard to run one after the other. They don't need to run at the same time.

I have tried simply `(action1) (action2)` side-by-side, but it only returns `action2`. Here is what I define for `action1` and `action2`:

```
(define ax 
  (lambda ()
    (+ 1 2)))
(define bx 
  (lambda ()
    (+ 5 2)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Executing one procedure after the other is as simple as this:

```
(define seq-action
  (lambda (action1 action2)
    (action1)
    (action2)))
```

However, the above will only return the result of the last procedure. If you need both results then return a list with the values, like this:

```
(define seq-action
  (lambda (action1 action2)
    (list (action1) (action2))))
```

Alternatively, you could return multiple values *simultaneously* using the `values` procedure:

```
(define seq-action
  (lambda (action1 action2)
    (values (action1) (action2))))
```

For retrieving both values after calling the last version, you need to use `let-values`.

Comment: In your first code you could also use `(begin (action1) (action2))` since it works "everywhere".

Comment: @ReyCharles `begin` is implicit inside a procedure, there's no need to  write it explicitly

Comment: I am aware of that. I'm suggesting it for pedagogical reasons. I believe there's a point in showing first the general case and then the "syntactic sugar" for the lambda-case. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the values function

Answer (score 1):

A Scheme function will return whatever the last thing it evaluated is.  If you need both returns you could try packing them into a list and returning it.

Comment: That explains why I thought only one item was executing. I needed to output both items without being part of a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check arguments against `procedure?` before calling, you may use the following solution.

```
(define seq-action
  (lambda (action1 action2)
    (and (procedure? action1) (action1))
    (and (procedure? action2) (action2))))
```